# Facet of/facet to

Tags: prepositions

*She has many facets **to** her personality*

*She has many facets **of** her personality*

*The only redeeming facet **of** the group was a boy*

Why is it so? How 'to and of' prepositions are used in these sentences?

Comment: She has many facets to his personality (**wrong**); She has many facets of his personality (**right**)

Comment: Note that "she" and "his" do not go together. Remember that in English most nouns do not have a gender (exceptions are vixen, son, mother etc.). Even so the gender goes with the possessor not the possessed.  Example: *John has a vixen living in his back yard. ***He*** treats ***his*** foxy friend with great respect."   You could also say, "***She sees*** many facets of ***his*** personality, because we are discussing the relationship between two different people and using a transitive verb "see".

Comment: P.S. Please could you correct this one way or the other by editing your question. At the moment the sentences don't make sense so we can't answer properly. Thanks.

Comment: Just as a comment, in British English people tend to talk about ‘redeeming features’ rather than ‘redeeming facets’.

Comment: @Greybeard Actually I have seen the 1st 
sentence on the internet itself . It could be a an error maybe. So, does only 'of' preposition goes with the word  facet?

Comment: @Tripti1234 No. Facet in, on, for, to, are all possible (and there are probably other possibilities.)  *Actually I have seen the 1st sentence on the internet itself* **1** Was that before or after you corrected it? **2** Rule number 124 says "Don't believe everything on the internet." :)

Comment: Little Mary has many facets of her father's personality.= She has many facets of his personality. Not that I like having facets much, but still.

Comment: @Greybeard. Yes, after the correction ( it was a typing error before). I understood both your examples below. Thank u:). As for the last example, it is from the book 'The fault in our stars' - "The only redeeming facet of Support Group was the kid named Isaac.."

Comment: @Tripti1234 The last example make sense when it is written in full. Your example does not. You should always give the whole quote, and some context. It is impossible to over-emphasise how important context is to English.

Answer (score 1):

> She has many facets to her personality.

This means "She has many facets **that belong to** or **that comprise** her own personality.

> She has many facets of her personality.

This is simply wrong... It is a very bad example because "she" and "her" **must** refer to different people if the sentence is to make sense.

***Mary** has many facets of **Jane's** personality.*"

This means "Mary has many facets **that are associated with** [facets of] Jane's personality, i.e. Mary shares some of Jane's facets.

> The only redeeming facet of the group was a boy

This is another poor example.

Comment: [June is Mary's mother]. She (Mary) has many facets of her [her mother's]  personality.

Answer (score 0):

Noting some of the comments, I think it's worth looking at a couple of usage charts. First....

[image][<sup>(Link)</sup>](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=are%20many%20facets%20to%2Care%20many%20facets%20of%2C((have%20many%20facets%20to)*20)%2C((have%20many%20facets%20of)*20)&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Care%20many%20facets%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Care%20many%20facets%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28%28have%20many%20facets%20to%29%20%2A%2020%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28%28have%20many%20facets%20of%29%20%2A%2020%29%3B%2Cc0)

...where I multiplied the figures for the less-common ***have*** context so they'd all fit on the same chart. I'm only interested in *relative* prevalence of the *prepositions*, and the chart clearly shows that ***to*** is far more common than ***of***.

---

But it's a completely different story if we switch the context to ***the** many facets...*

[image]
[<sup>(Link)</sup>](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20many%20facets%20to%2Cthe%20many%20facets%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20many%20facets%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20many%20facets%20of%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cthe%20many%20facets%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20many%20facets%20of%3B%2Cc0)

...where suddenly we find that ***to*** is practically unknown. I don't know if it helps, but expanding on [@Lambie's comment above...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/538760/facet-of-facet-to#comment1319393_538760)

> *(Mary is an unusual character, as was her father...)*
> 1: *She has many facets **to her** personality*
> 2: *She has many facets **of his** personality*
> 3: *She has many facets **of her** personality* ???
> 4: *She has many facets **to his** personality* ???

It's not obvious to me how to describe the syntactic principle involved in the choice of prepositions above, but there's no doubt that practically all native speakers would accept #1 & #2 there, and reject #3 & #4.

Comment: Mary has many facets of her mother's personality. She/her is fine there.

Comment: Check the example context again! (there is no contextually-relevant "mother") I specifically chose female ***Mary*** and male ***her father*** so there would be no misunderstanding about ***whose*** personality (Mary's of the father's) was being referenced by preceding ***her, his***.

Comment: "*the chart clearly shows that to is far more common than of.*" unfortunately, ubiquity is not the same as "correct in context". **To**, and **of** both produce a dative of association (Cf German "zu" and "von":) "**To**" tends to carry a broad meaning of "*towards*" and "*of*" tends to carry an indication of the origin (cf. "from").